# Is there a built in interface for Doubly, Circular Linked List In Java?

Tags: java, data-structures

Since we have a built in interface for Singly linked list in java `( import java.util.LinkedList )` . Do we also have a Doubly, Circular Linked List in java too? If not, can we alter the already present Singly Linked List to doubly and circular?

Comment: [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) *is* a doubly-linked list - it says so at the very beginning of the reference page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do we also have a Doubly, Circular Linked List in java too?

The standard library's `LinkedList` is doubly-linked but not circular.

> If not, can we alter the already present Singly Linked List to doubly and circular?

See above. You cannot alter it in place, but you could do any of the following:

1. Write a `DoublyLinkedList` from scratch, or
2. Subclass `LinkedList` and use that as a starting point,
3. [Subclass any of `LinkedList`'s ancestors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and use that as a starting point.

EDIT: [Apache Commons contains `CursorableLinkedList`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/list/CursorableLinkedList.html), which is doubly-linked, but it's not clear from the description whether or not it's circular. I'm guessing it's not. You could also subclass that and modify it to be circular.